# How do I implement the Serializable interface to serialize/unserialize a class to/from native type

Tags: php, object, serialization, integration, php-5.5

The below is my class:

```
class Pot implements Serializable
{
    protected $a=1;
    protected $b=2;

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(['a'=>$this->a,'b'=>$this->b]);
    }
    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        $values = unserialize($data);
        $this->a = $values['a'];
        $this->b = $values['b'];
    }
}

$Ser = serialize(new Pot);
//THIS IS WHAT I NEED:
// a:2:{s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";i:2;}
```

I would like the class to be serialized as a simple array, as I need to pass it to an external system, But still would like to unserialize it in my system into the original class.
How?

Comment: Yes, it is totally different question. I flagged that question to be deleted by admins.
The big difference is the value of the serialized string I need back from the serialize function

Answer (score 1):

If you serialize it as a simple array then the system has no way of telling it was originally a `Pot`, so you won't be able to get a `Pot` back that way when you unserialize. What if you have a class called `Box` that you also wanted to serialize as an array. How would the system know which class should be instantiated?

Likely you'll have to do this:

- Write a specific method that returns the array you want from your `Pot` class.
- Use that to get your serialized string so it has no class info.
- Then you'll need some kind of factory function/class that takes a serialized array and creates a Pot class then sets the properties using setters/constructorIf they're not all going to be `Pots` then you'll need to know which strings you want to turn into `Pots` too. (I suspect that bit won't be a problem, though.)

The `Serialize` interface will not really help you with this problem. I don't think.

Comment: thanks ... that is what I do at the moment, hoped there was a more built-in way to do this.

Comment: Nope don't think so. Once it's a simple array (serialized) the system just won't be able to tell what it was before.

Comment: I can theoretically think of a way with casting and implementing an unserialize function inside the object I cast to the simple array. The php engine would then know to send this string to the right place. I feel now this is something to be discussed at the PHP Internals developer group